# Mongo DB GUI for Meteor project setup in AWS

Tags: mongodb, meteor, amazon-ec2

I had set up a meteor project in aws server and I can access DB using the command line. But how can I get GUI for the DB?

Thanks.

Comment: you can use robomongo client to connect to mongo server. if that's you meant by "GUI for the DB"
https://robomongo.org/

Comment: Robo 3T (https://robomongo.org/download) really is good. I like to use it for prototyping and query testing.

Comment: Thank you, but when i provide  "meteor mongo --url", getting "mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor" local url, how can i connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used adminMongo, this would work like phpmyadmin for mongoDB

https://github.com/mrvautin/adminMongo

I have installed it on db.mydomain.com and added HTTP password for security.

Answer (score 2):

I really recommending for you to try [Robomongo solutions](https://robomongo.org/). I really like Robo 3T, because it gives me an access to all MongoDB functionlities (unlike some other analogs from the other companies). It's cross-platform, light-weight and free.

Comment: Thank you, but when i provide  "meteor mongo --url", getting "mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor" local url, how can i connect?

Comment: You need to create a new connection. Go to File > Connect (or Ctrl + N), then press on Create link and in the Connection tab you need to enter the address (127.0.0.1 or localhost) and port (3001) values.

Comment: When i enter the address (127.0.0.1 or localhost), it connects local db. I need to connect server db. How can i get server db path?

Comment: If the MongoDB configuration allows connections from the outside, then just enter the server IP (or url) into `Connection > Address` field. Or you can connect to MongoDB via SSH tunnel (take a look into `SSH` tab).